# Cancel insert when field is empty

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a combobox called "cboproduct" and a field called "quantity". 
Now when a value is entered in the field quantity but nothing is selected  from cboproduct, a warning should pop up and the focus should return to cboproduct.
How do I achieve the above?

Answer (score 1):

Use the *BeforeUpdate* event of the form:

```
Cancel = IsNull(Me!cboProduct.Value)

If Cancel = True Then
    MsgBox "Enter product."
    Me!cboProduct.SetFocus
End If
```